# Visual Basic simple shuffle routine

Tags: vb.net, shuffle

I need to shuffle an array of 4 numbers in Visual Basic.
Tried lots of different code snippets but none seem to work for me.
Looking for simple as possible solution.

Comment: Literally tons of shuffling examples here at SO. Show us your declaration of your array so we know what you've actually got.

Comment: Fisher-Yates is a well-known in-place shuffle algorithm that should be straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This code works whatever the length of your array is:

```
Dim temp As Integer
Dim rand As New Random
Dim r As Integer

For x As Integer = 0 To _yourArray.Count - 1
       temp = _yourArray(x)
       r = rand.Next(1, _yourArray.Count)
       _yourArray(x) = _yourArray(r)
       _yourArray(r) = temp
Next
```